# Getting visitors email ids in Joomla

Tags: joomla

How to let visitors of the website provide their email ids, optionally, for further future communication with them. Its not specifically a newsletter subscription or anything (but could as well be) but just a polite pop-up on visiting a page, asking them to provide their email address, if they wish to be contacted sometime in future.

- this is to run on a Joomla based website.
- just a simple form (can be a pop-up) that asks for user email ids and then stores it in the database.
- Not a Mailing List subscription or anything like it (so no auto-responder subscription needed)

Thanks

This should be very easy for the people that know !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a ready-made extension available for this, but there are some extensions that you can use as examples to put together something yourself. You could look at newsletter subscription components and modules to see how they make a form for receiving a name and email address, and how they save it to the database. You could also look into extensions that use Squeezebox, the built-in Lightbox look-alike, or you could check one of the login modules that popup.

However, I think you would be ready most quickly if you would just install a newsletter component, change the text of the subscription module (and possibly corresponding changes to front-end component output), and then you simply don't send newsletters. In this way you would start building a database table with names and email adresses as you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive sm2email can do it:

http://sm2extensions.com/content/view/143/105/